# Sticky footer with flexbox on body and children

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, sticky-footer

I want to use a simple flexbox layout with header, section (consisting of aside and section) and a sticky footer.

My problem is, that when I apply `display:flex` to the body and to at minimum one child (it doesn't matter if it's header, section or footer) only firefox does it like I need to.

```css
html, body {
 height:100vh;
 min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

section {
 flex: 1;
 display: flex;
}
section section {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>

 <header>
  <h1>Test Flexbox</h1>
 </header>
  
 <section>
   <aside>
   <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
 </aside>
    
   <section>
  <article>
          <h2>Test</h2>
          <p>Welome to this flex box test snippet.</p>
        </article>
      </section>
    
  </section>

 <footer>
  <p>Here goes the footer, that should always stick to the bottom</p>
 </footer>

</body>
```

The above code works in Firefox but does not work in Chrome, Opera, Safari (and probably more).

If I apply the `display:flex` to a `<div>` after the body instead, it works everywhere.

Is this a bug or is it not allowed/recommended to use flexbox on the body-element?

**EDIT:**
Here is the alternative-version using a div which works in all browsers:

```css
html, body {
 height:100vh;
 min-height: 100vh;
}

div {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

section {
 flex: 1;
 display: flex;
}
section section {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<body><div>

 <header>
  <h1>Test Flexbox</h1>
 </header>
  
 <section>
   <aside>
   <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
      <p>Test Test Test</p>
 </aside>
    
   <section>
  <article>
          <h2>Test</h2>
          <p>Welome to this flex box test snippet.</p>
        </article>
      </section>
    
  </section>

 <footer>
  <p>Here goes the footer, that should always stick to the bottom</p>
 </footer>

</div></body>
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample that works when using a `div`? And btw, Flexbox can be used on the `body`.

Comment: @LGSon added the 'div' version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using viewport units, no need to set it on all items, in this case the `body` is enough. Also, drop the `height: 100vh` and it will work fine.

*Note 1; the `div` version works, kind of, but not fully either, because you didn't gave it `height`/`min-height` as the `body` has.*

*Note 2; I read somewhere that when using both `height`/`min-height` with the same value, it could go wrong/be buggy in some browsers, which might be the case here. When I find where it was, I'll update my answer.*

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

section section {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Test Flexbox</h1>
</header>

<section>
  <aside>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
  </aside>

  <section>
    <article>
      <h2>Test</h2>
      <p>Welome to this flex box test snippet.</p>
    </article>
  </section>

</section>

<footer>
  <p>Here goes the footer, that should always stick to the bottom</p>
</footer>
```

---

Updated; to support IE11, which has a `min-height` bug, do like this:

```css
html {
  display: flex;                   /*  IE bug fix  */
}

body {
  width: 100%;                     /*  flex row item need this to
                                       take full width  */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section {
  flex-grow: 1;                    /*  IE need this  */
  display: flex;
}

section section {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Test Flexbox</h1>
</header>

<section>
  <aside>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
    <p>Test Test Test</p>
  </aside>

  <section>
    <article>
      <h2>Test</h2>
      <p>Welome to this flex box test snippet.</p>
    </article>
  </section>

</section>

<footer>
  <p>Here goes the footer, that should always stick to the bottom</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that the the div version don't work at all :)